# VBA Update Existing Records

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was looking to setup VBA that would add new records to a table, if they did not currently exist (same ID #) and then update all of the columns for existing records (same ID #). I was able to setup the insert statement, but am coming up with errors for updating.

The code below states that I have a

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[update].[date] from [update].

Any help you may provide would be very helpful.

```
Function Update()
    Dim dbs As Database
    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    dbs.Execute "Update historic_archive Set historic_archive.DATE = [update].[DATE] FROM [update], historic_archive WHERE [update].[id] = historic_archive.id;"

End Function
```

Comment: *Do not ever* use keywords as your objects names.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to update those now and see if that helps. :-)

Comment: That's a best practice that JohnyL is encouraging, it's not your problem.

Comment: See [Update Query Examples](https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/snytax/update-query.html#Update_Query_Examples) and look at the example under "Update with Values from Fields in Another Table" heading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things.
1. Please read more about SQL update command.
2. Never use names that resemble functions like date, update. Read more about naming conventions.

```
'Below update command will update historic date with update table.date where both id's are same.


Function Update() 
    Dim dbs As Database 
    Set dbs = CurrentDb 

    dbs.Execute "UPDATE historic_archive inner join [UPDATE] ON [update].[id] = historic_archive.id " & _
    "SET historic_archive.[DATE] = [update].[DATE];"
End Function
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much for taking the time to review my inquiry. I am very grateful for all of the responses provided.

Comment: Please complete your question by marking answered. @Bruins1

Comment: This 2+ year old answer just put an end to an hour of thrashing. JOIN first, then SET. Wish MS Docs would mention this in Remarks. Must be common task during De-Normalization.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to change your "WHERE" to "ON"

```
Function Update()

  Dim dbs As Database

  Set dbs = CurrentDb

  dbs.Execute "UPDATE historic_archive " _
            & "SET historic_archive.DATE = [update].[DATE] " _
            & "FROM [update] " _
            & "JOIN historic_archive ON [update].[id] = historic_archive.id;"

End Function
```

Comment: I will try that!! Thank you!!

Comment: Hello again! I copied and pasted that in. However, I am receiving the same error?

Comment: Try this (edited answer), the join needed to be explicit.

Comment: Hello, I tried that code and got a different error.

Comment: Error- Run-time error ‘3075’: 

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ‘[update].[date] from [update] join historic_table on [update].[id] = historic_table.id’.

Comment: That error return doesn't show the query that I have provided.  `[update].[date] from [update] join historic_table on [update].[id] = historic_table.id` is not a valid query.

Comment: I wonder if you have some stray quotes or apostrophes in there somewhere.

Comment: This is what I have Function Update()

          Dim dbs As Database

  Set dbs = CurrentDb

          dbs.Execute "UPDATE historic_table " _
                    & "SET historic_table. DATE = [update].[DATE] " _
                    & "FROM [update] " _
                    & "JOIN historic_table ON [update].[ id] = historic_table. id;"

        End Function

Comment: Sorry- Trying to get used to the formatting on here.

Comment: Yes. I just pasted it

Comment: Are you in access?  It doesn't seem like Excel, as the tag suggests.

Comment: Yes. Sorry! I will try to fix that.

Comment: Yeah, that's your issue.  MS Access SQL is different syntax.